# Facebook OAuth dialog redirects to m.facebook.com and crashes with 500 error

Tags: facebook, oauth

I am using Facebook's OAuth dialog to log in people in two of my websites.

Yesterday morning I discovered that the oauth dialog is failing for one of those two website, *only* when I try to connect with a mobile device (iphone and android).
The way I call the oauth dialog is identical in both websites, except from the App ID of course and the redirect url. Basically I redirect the user to:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.xxxxx.xxx%2Ffbresult&response_type=code&scope=email
Normally the user is prompted for logging in with facebook and give permission to the app, and the be redirected back to my website.

This works perfectly fine on both sites if I use it from the Desktop.
When I call this url from my touch devices (iphone or android, they both fail) I am forcely redirected to the mobile version of the dialog (https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?etc,etc).
However this dialog from m.facebook.com dies with 500 internal server error for one of the website. (so: one works perfectly with mobile oauth dialog, the other does not).
I tried to open the m.facebook.com/etc/etc from my desktop pc and I could indeed see the 500 internal server error response.
Should I try to login from the desktop (which does not redirect to mobile version) then the authentication procedure works perfectly.

At first I thought this might be a facebook bug and that it would have been fixed within few hours at most, but it's been now for at least 2 days and still does not work.
I think I could really appreciate some advice at this point. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: how you solved ? i'm facing the same problem